# Elements of a ring which behave like multiplicative identity

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $0 \neq x \in R$, if whenever $xy = x$ for $1 \neq y \in R$ then ($y \in R$ is a zero divisor) there exists $0 \neq z \in R$ such that $zy = 0$.

Example: $\overline{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_6$.

I want to prove that if $xy$ satisfies the above property for $0 \neq x, 0 \neq y \in R$ then each $x$ and $y$ will satisfy it.

Please help me how to prove this and what you say about the converse?

Comment: question should be more clear; idempotent element $e$ (i.e. $e.e=e$) work like identity element for that element (and possibly some others). So if $xy=x$ **for all $y\in R$** then $x$ should be identity.

Answer (score 1):

As $R$ is commutative, $xy=yx$, so it is enough to show it for $x$.
Now let $z \in R$ be such that $z \neq 1$ and $xz = x$. Then we have $(xy)z = (xz)y = xy $, so as $xy$ has the desired property, there exists an $q \in R$ such that $qz=0$ and $q \neq 0$.

Comment: first we assume that $xy$ satisfying the given property and then prove it for $x$ and $y$ individually

Comment: Exactly, that is what is done here.